# rails showのID参照について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsを始めて2週間の新参者です、よろしくお願いします
現在scaffoldを使い
管理用scaffoldと閲覧用のindex show を作っています

説明が下手ですが、管理用のscaffoldに記事を投稿したら閲覧用の別のコントローラーを使用したindex showに記事が追加表示されるという仕組みを行いたいです
そこで、indexの記事の概要を並べる所は上手くいったのですが、その概要記事からリンクでshow(詳細記事)の記事に飛ぶときに下記エラーが発生します
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記のやり方ではIDが取得できないのでしょうか？そのまえに:IDをカラム追加しなければならないのでしょうか？他は何とかなるのですがここだけ悩み続けています

```ruby
class KotensController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @### = ###.all
  end

  def show
    @### = ###.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

ちなみに管理用と公開用でコントローラーを分けているのは今後管理用にアップローダー等別の機能も乗っける予定で分けております。
良いやり方をお教えくださいますと幸いです
よろしくお願いします

追記こちらリンク先(show)のViewになります

```
<h1>Coffee#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/coffee/show.html.erb</p>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @koten.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Place:</strong>
  <%= @koten.place %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @koten.date %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Time:</strong>
  <%= @koten.time %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Time:</strong>
  <%= @koten.time2 %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Setu:</strong>
  <%= @koten.setu %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Image:</strong>
<% if @koten.image? %>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= image_tag @koten.image.url %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</p>

<%= link_to '戻る', root_path %>
```

追記：routeになります

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :kotens 
  resources :coffee, only: [:index, :show]
  root :to => 'coffee#index'
  get'/show/:id' => 'kotens#show'
  get'/show/:id' => 'coffee#show'

end
```

Comment: 概要記事からリンクを張っている部分のviewのコード、エラーが出ている画面のURLなども合わせてあると、回答しやすそうです

Comment: 回答編集ありがとうございます！

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。indexの方のリンクに原因がありそうな気がします。indexのviewのコードもあると回答しやすそうです!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

恐らくリンク元のindexのページで、`link_to`のリンクがうまく生成できていなさそうです。

`params[:id]`をみると、モデルのid属性が渡されておらず、ActiveRecord Relationが渡されているように見えます。

indexのviewのソースを見ないとなんともいえないのですが、indexのviewで`link_to koten_path(@kotens)`のように書いてある部分を`link_to koten_path(@kotens[0])`のように修正するとうまく動くのではないでしょうか。